# Custom Headers for leanback BrowseFragment with PageRow

Tags: android, android-tv, leanback, browsefragment

The code consists of a BrowseFragment that has multiple list rows associated to each header row, in reference to this code, i was able to implement it correctly using PageRow instead of ListRow
(https://github.com/googlesamples/leanback-showcase/blob/master/app/src/main/java/android/support/v17/leanback/supportleanbackshowcase/app/page/PageAndListRowFragment.java)

The problem is with this function that helps me customize the headers (add icon to the headers:

[image]

```
browseFragment.setHeaderPresenterSelector(new PresenterSelector() {
        @Override
        public IconHeaderPresenter getPresenter(Object item) {
            return new IconHeaderPresenter();
        }

    });
```

Once I add it, the headers are no longer selected, and I can't navigate between them.

This is how I am creating the browsefragment:

```
    ...     
    browseFragment = new BrowseFragment();
    browseFragment.setHeadersState(BrowseFragment.HEADERS_ENABLED);
    browseFragment.prepareEntranceTransition();
    browseFragment.setHeaderPresenterSelector(new PresenterSelector() {
        @Override
        public IconHeaderPresenter getPresenter(Object item) {
            return new IconHeaderPresenter();
        }

    });

    mBackgroundManager = BackgroundManager.getInstance(shared.main);
    mBackgroundManager.attach(shared.main.getWindow());
    browseFragment.getMainFragmentRegistry().registerFragment(IconPageRow.class,
            new PageRowFragmentFactory(mBackgroundManager));
```

...

```
private static class PageRowFragmentFactory extends BrowseFragment.FragmentFactory {
    private final BackgroundManager mBackgroundManager;

    PageRowFragmentFactory(BackgroundManager backgroundManager) {
        this.mBackgroundManager = backgroundManager;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment createFragment(Object rowObj) {
        ArrayObjectAdapter adapter=((IconPageRow)rowObj).getAdapter();
        RowsFragment rowsFragment = new RowsFragment();
        rowsFragment.enableRowScaling(true);
        rowsFragment.setAdapter(adapter);
        mBackgroundManager.setDrawable(null);
        rowsFragment.setOnItemViewClickedListener(browseClickListener);
        rowsFragment.setOnItemViewSelectedListener(browseSelectedListener);
        return rowsFragment;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution to this was to add to my Custom Header presenter (IconHeaderPresenter) in onCreateViewHolder these two lines:

```
view.setFocusable(true);
view.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
```

Comment: I am working on creating custom menu for android TV. Can you share the sample code? @nadine87

Answer (score 2):

In IconHeaderPresenter().

**View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.icon_header_item, null);**

**icon_header_item.xml** is as below:

```
<android.support.v17.leanback.widget.ImageCardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/fastlane_background"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    android:contextClickable="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">
//your layout here
</android.support.v17.leanback.widget.ImageCardView>
```

Comment: I was scratching my head on this problem from past 1 month,i hope this will help others too.Happy Coding :)

Comment: @shyam002 Can I ask you to post IconHeaderItemPresenter I would to see how ViewHolder look like .